# How to store the multiple list in Jlist in a string?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jlist

I think I am lost here in this interesting situation.
I have a `Jlist` containing suppose 3 elements in it.
I want to select all the three at once using cntrl button and click on `JButton` so that all the three elements get stored in string.
I am confused here as whether I am going the right way or not because how can we store the `list` elements in a string and also **`java throwing compilation error :  java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;`**

why I need to store this in a string because I want to make a loop and reiterates it using the three elements.

Could any of you have suggestion for this piece?
Please help

Comment: We can't help you with a compile-time error in code you haven't posted (hint hint).

Comment: >java throwing compilation error : java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

It seems that you are trying to cast String value to String[]

Comment: List elements returns Objects(hope you are using list....toArray()))